# onSharedPreferenceChanged method enters in an endless loop?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

The method `onSharedPreferenceChanged` enters in an infinite loop. I don't understand why changing the preference causes the event to fire again.

```
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if(key.equals("theme")){
            Log.d("THEME", sharedPreferences.getBoolean("theme", false) ? "true" : "false");
            boolean isDark = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("theme", false);
            if(isDark)
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("theme", false).apply();
            else
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("theme", true).apply();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are changing preference inside `onSharedPreferenceChanged` what do you expect from this code ? It will enter in infinite recursion .

Comment: I can see that, but I don't know where I am supposed to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onSharedPreferenceChanged() invoked while you change the preference value.You always change the preference value inside the onSharedPreferenceChanged() and it work as an infinite loop.

Comment: then where should I change the property?

Comment: When you want to change the preference value?

Comment: I think I realised my mistake. I have a switch option in my preference xml, I want to change the value when the button is pressed. I guess I should i just add the listener for the switch and not on the shared preference.